# My script doesn't run according to cron schedule

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, cron

I have made (with a Stack Exchange help) a script that checks if the web application is available and restarts the web app daemon in order to get it running again (usually helps until I'm at work). It's supposed to run every hour.

I've added the following line to `sudo crontab -e`:

```
0 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh
```

The contents of `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
HTTP_STATUS=$(lynx -head -source https://example.com |head -1 |awk '{print $2}')
calendar=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y - %H:%M")
LOG="Log is placed in /usr/local/bin/test.log"

if [ "$HTTP_STATUS" = "503" ]
then
    systemctl restart mydaemon

    echo "$calendar - site unavailable ($HTTP_STATUS). Daemon restarted." >> test.log
elif [ "$HTTP_STATUS" = "200" ]
then
    echo "$calendar - site available ($HTTP_STATUS)" >> test.log
else
    echo "$calendar - site status unknown ($HTTP_STATUS)" >> test.log
fi
```

I have two other scripts in scheduled in cron that work just fine, only that they run every midnight. All of my scripts have same permissions and same owner.

My `test.log` file is not updated every hour so I suppose the script doesn't run. Running the script manually creates log entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

crontab runs scripts in a different environment from login shell; in particular, PATH could be different or undefined.

Try to use absolute path on the commands (lynx, head ...) 
You can get them with

```
which <command>
```

Moreover you should specify path for test.log.

Comment: The problem is that if I run the script manually, everything is fine. For some reason, cron doesn't run this particular script every hour. I have two other scripts that are similar and work properly.
Edit: ah I understand what you mean now, sorry. I will try to put absolute paths in my script.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had to put an absolute path to ```test.log``` - I assumed it would write log to the location of script file.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is running just fine, but it writes to a file called `test.log` in the current directory.  Since you never `cd` in your script, the current directory technically be anywhere, but it's most likely the user's home directory.

To write to `test.log` located elsewhere, either `cd` to the correct directory in the script, or provide the full path to the `test.log` file when redirecting to it.

Also note that you are doing needlessly many redirections to the output file.  If *all* output from your `if` statement should be appended to the log file, you might as well do

```sh
if ...; then
   ...
elif ...; then
   ...
else
   ...
if >>/path/to/test.log
```

which would redirect all output from within the `if` statement to the file.

Or, if *all* output from the script should be redirected to the log file, you may as well redirect from the crontab with

```
0 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh >>/path/to/test.log
```

(some crontabs support `@hourly` as a shortcut for writing `0 * * * *` by the way, check `man 5 crontab` on your system).

Tag on `2>&1` after the redirection of standard output to the file to also redirect the standard error stream (i.e. `... >/path/to/test.log 2>&1`).

Additionally, you have `/bin/sh` in the script's `#!` line, but you run the script with `bash` explicitly from the crontab.  This is confusing. As far as I can see, there's nothing `bash`-specific in your script, so either run it with `/bin/sh` from crontab, or just make it executable and *don't* specify an interpreter on the command line in crontab to run it.

---

My take on your script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y - %H:%M")
logfile=/usr/local/bin/test.log

status=$( lynx -head -source 'https://example.com' | awk 'FNR == 1 { print $2 }' )

case $status in
    503)
        systemctl restart mydaemon
        message='Daemon restarted, site was unavailable'
        ;;
    200)
        message='Site is available'
        ;;
    *)
        message='Site status is unknown'
esac

printf '%s: %s (status=%s)\n' "$now" "$message" "$status" >>"$logfile"
```